# How to alter Stanford NLP output, so that it is compatible with Apache Open NLP format for POS tagging and Chunking?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, opennlp

Apache OpenNLP formats POS and Chunks somewhat differently than Stanford NLP as per https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.chunker

Using "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."

```
Apache OpenNLP POS: The_DT quick_JJ brown_JJ fox_NN jumped_VBD over_IN the_DT lazy_JJ dog_NN ._.

Apache OpenNLP Chunk:  [NP The_DT quick_JJ brown_JJ fox_NN ] [VP jumped_VBD ] [PP over_IN ] [NP the_DT lazy_JJ dog_NN ] ._.
```

I noticed the Stanford Parser does provide Chunks and POS in a full parse and looks like this:

```
(ROOT\n  (S\n    (NP (DT The) (JJ quick) (JJ brown) (NN fox))\n    (VP (VBD jumped)\n      (PP (IN over)\n        (NP (DT the) (JJ lazy) (NN dog.))))))
```

How can we modify the output, so that it becomes compatible with Apache OpenNLP?

I do notice that Stanford NLP uses nested phrases, eg the verb phrase contains a Prepositional as well as a noun phrase...